# How to decide if a "Device " need an Operating System or not

Tags: operating-system, embed, device

How to decide if a "Device " need an Operating System(embedded OS ) or not?

This is a general interview question. 
Any thought?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, if more then one application needs to be run on that device, it should have an operating system. Otherwise it would be a waste.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience an operating system is essentially used

- to manage resources on the device like scheduling tasks, allocating resource etc and
- to abstract away some of the low level hardware interface like thread handling, interrupt handling etc.

If either of these functions are needed it might be a good idea to use an operating system. Now of course in all cases some form of the above two functions will be needed. But in simple devices it might be just easier to code up the specific function instead of trying to port an OS to the device. But in other cases where the device is a lot more complex it might be a better investment of time to try and use an OS versus having to code it all up.